# Looking for database system for archive data

Tags: mysql, mongodb, archive

I need to build application with big data (archive) . 
I try mongo and mysql but both need much memory .
ex. Mongo need 10G ram for 30G database .
I need a database use less memory , have index , write can slow ,acceptable read .

Comment: I don't have the experience to give you a real answer, but I found this blog: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com that might be helpful. There was an article there specifically about memory to data ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the index? If you can forego the index you might want to look at the [MySQL ARCHIVE Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/archive-storage-engine.html).

Alternatively, since speed is not a factor, might you be able to compress a portion of the data? If the data is uncompressable, can you store it on a filesystem with links to the data from an indexed database? What are your hardware and OS constraints?